# How to change the dgrid-expando-icon in Tree dgrid

Tags: dojo, dgrid

Could you please help, how to change the triangle icon expand/collapse to my custom icon (+,-) in the Tree grid.  Also, how to remove all the table borders in the grid.Hoping it can be done through css.

@Himanshu - This is not a dojoxGrid rather a dgrid. I looked up in the dgrid.css to see , if I can find something similar, and found these.How do I represent the four states expand(normal,hover) and collapse(normal, hover).

```
 .dgrid-expando-icon {
 width: 16px;
 height: 16px;
}    
ui-icon {
 width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-image: url("images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png");
}
```

[image: Expandor Icon]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following CSS in order to change the default icon for `dojox.grid.TreeGrid`.

`!important` allows you to override the default CSS property value.

```
.dojoxGridExpandoNode {
    background-image: url('http://findicons.com/files/icons/2625/google_plus_interface_icons/18/star.png') !important;
}
```

Live example, changin plus icon to a start:

http://jsfiddle.net/zx4g3z02/2/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm using a dgrid and not a dojox TreeGrid. Let me try your example on the Tree Grid and see if its works. I'm thinking I would need to manipulate 2 icons expand and collapse as well, overriding with !important.

Comment: .ui-icon-triangle-1-e {
  background-position: -32px -16px;
  background-image: url("images/relate_plus.png") !important;
  
}
.ui-icon-triangle-1-se {
  background-position: -48px -16px;
  background-image: url("images/relate_minus.png") !important;
  
}

Answer (score 0):

The expand/ collapse icon comes from the `background-image` property of the `div` corresponding to the class `dojoxGridExpandoNode`. So you can override its CSS and apply your own `background-image` property.

By default, the image is a combination of four images, that has two images for expand (normal and hover) and two images for collapse (normal and hover) and only the `background-position` property is changed during the `onmouseover` and the `onlcick` on the icon node. So you will have to make your custom image accordingly. Or override the `onmouseover` and `onclick` functionality of the expand/ collapse node to manipulate the image accordingly.

Comment: @ Himanshu , Please see my edited question again. Appreciate your help. Also, I was able to remove the borders with .claro .dgrid-cell {border:none;}

Comment: Oh, I thought it was a `dojox.grid.TreeGrid`. Well, since it's a `dgrid` and you can see that the image used for `background-image` has all the images that are required in a `dgrid`. To change, there are two possible ways here. One is to change the icons in the image by the ones that you require. Here, you won't be required to do any other change. Second way is to look up the functionality of expand and collapse and wherever the CSS has been changed to manipulate the `background-position`, at that point change the `background-image` as well and show your images.